# Subquery caching in join

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, subquery, query-cache

I have very complex MySQL queries that use the same subquery over and over again. I was wondering if MySQL will run the subquery multiple times or use the previous resultset. Is there any way to tell MySQL to save or cache the results?

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    pc.categoryId,
    COUNT(pc.productId)
FROM
    product_categories pc
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        t1.productId AS s1
    FROM
        product_categories t1
    JOIN
        product_highlights t2
    ON
        t1.productId = t2.productId
    WHERE
        t1.categoryId IN(7, 5) AND t2.highlightId IN(9, 10, 11)
    GROUP BY
        t1.productId
    HAVING
        2 * 3 = COUNT(
            DISTINCT t1.categoryId,
            t2.highlightId
        )
) productsIds
ON
    pc.productId = productsIds.s1
GROUP BY
    pc.categoryId
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is EXPLAIN query:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    4 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pc         | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    5 |    20.00 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t1         | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    5 |    80.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t2         | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    7 |    14.29 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/804ef/1/0) of my database.

**UPDATE 2:**

Temporary table query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempProducts
(
    tmpProductId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(tmpProductId)
) ENGINE = MEMORY 

SELECT
    t1.productId AS tmpProductId
FROM
    product_categories t1
JOIN product_highlights t2 ON
    t1.productId = t2.productId
WHERE
    t1.categoryId IN(7, 5) AND t2.highlightId IN(9, 10, 11)
GROUP BY
    t1.productId
HAVING
    2 * 3 = COUNT(
        DISTINCT t1.categoryId,
        t2.highlightId
    );
```

Temp table will look like:

```
+--------------+
| tmpProductId |
+--------------+
|            1 |
|            2 |
+--------------+
```

`> show index from tempProducts where Key_name = 'PRIMARY'`

```
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tempproducts |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | tmpProductId | NULL      |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |               |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Query with temporary table:

```
SELECT
    categoryId,
    COUNT(productId)
FROM
    product_categories tb1
INNER JOIN tempProducts tb2 ON
    tb1.productId = tb2.tmpProductId
GROUP BY
    categoryId;
```

I added composite `UNIQUE` index to `product_categories` table: 
`UNIQUE(productId, categoryId)`

`EXPLAIN` query:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys               | key     | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | index  | productId_categoryId_unique | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL             |    5 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY | 2       | ss.tb1.productId |    1 |             |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: *I was wondering if MySQL will run the subquery multiple times or use the previous resultset.* Yes. *Is there any way to tell MySQL to save or cache the results?* If your queries which uses this subq are executed one-by-one in the same connection than you can store subq result into temporary table (and maybe ever create some indices on it) than use it in your queries. Of course you can try to convert this subq to view but I'm not sure that its result will be cached into query cache and re-used.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` against the whole query.  With that we can discuss this particular case, then discuss other possible cases.

Comment: `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, not an Optimization.

Comment: @Akina, thank you for your reply. Actually, the temp table perfectly fits my case. But I am concerning about performance. Approximately 1500 rows will be in a temp table with one smallint, PK column, which equals (1500 x 2bytes) 3 kilobytes. If I choose the engine of my temp table as `Memory`, will it cause performance problems? I can spare enough space for MySQL heap.

Comment: @RickJames I added `EXPLAIN` query.  Please, take a look at it.

Comment: Compact temptable on MEMORY engine cannot cause any problem. Of course your size calc is too approximate because of pagination, but its overhead is small enough.

Comment: MariaDB has a subquery cache that might automatically kick in for your case.

Comment: @RickJames thank you for your reply! Please take a look at the following paragraph from [src](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/03/02/look-mariadb-subquery-cache/). _the MariaDB subquery cache is not a query cache for subqueries. These features are different, implemented for different purposes. Obviously, the subquery cache doesn’t have the scalability and performance problems of the query cache (global mutex, table invalidation). As mentioned, a subquery cache table only survives for the duration of a statement, so it should be considered an optimizer strategy._

Comment: @RickJames, Please, correct me if I'm wrong. As far as I understand, it means if I run different queries one by one with the same query, the subquery cache will not work, because it only survives for the duration of a statement.

Comment: @Shahin - Correct.  My suggestion does not apply.

Comment: @Shahin - Is the "subquery" in question the "derived table" named `productsIds`?  If you turn that into a temp table, what would it look like?  What indexes would you add?  Is there any chance that the data would be invalid due to writes between uses?

Comment: @RickJames, _Is the "subquery" in question the "derived table" named productsIds_ Yes, exactly. I need only `productId` from that subquery and it will be `smallint` column, since all product ids are unique, can I use them as  primary keys? Please take a look at it update 2 section for details.  _Is there any chance that the data would be invalid due to writes between uses?_ Actually no, there will be rare writes but intensive selects.

Comment: @RickJames, thank you for your help! Please, let me clarify one more thing. MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html)  says: _Hash indexes are used only for equality comparisons that use the = or <=> operators (but are very fast)._ If the temp table will be using only for joins I should  stick up with `hash index`, right? It will be faster than `B-tree`?

Comment: @Shahin - If you are using `BEGIN...COMMIT`, then concurrent writes will (in most cases) be delayed.  Consider using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: @Shahin - InnoDB does not support Hash `INDEXes`.  BTree indexes are virtually as fast, so don't worry.  `MEMORY` has Hash.

Comment: @Shahin - Show us the `EXPLAIN` after building and using the temp table.

Comment: @RickJames, there will be no updates and inserts in temp table, only selects. Thank you for informing though.

Comment: @RickJames, I am using `Memory` to store my table, not `InnoDB`. As far as I know the `Memory` is much faster than `InnoDB`. Please take a look at Update 2 section for details, `Index_type` is `HASH`. I also added query and `EXPLAIN` of that with temporary table, please take a look at UPDATE 3 section. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @RickJames, hello sir. I need to clarify something, wondering if you could help me out. Are temporary tables created on `MEMORY` or disk if I don't specify an engine? If I specify `InnoDB` as an engine and spare enough amount of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` temporary tables will be stored in `MEMORY`, not on the disk, right?

Comment: @Shahin - In _some_ cases `MEMORY` is faster than InnoDB; it depends on locking.  Temp tables _may_ be `MEMORY` or may by `MyISAM`, depending on several things.  (8.0 may changing to InnoDB.)  Your tests _may not_ be representative because of having so few rows.

Comment: If you use `MEMORY`, you are taking away from RAM that could be used in the buffer_pool.  In general, it is best to do nothing and let MySQL pick the engine based on its well-tuned code.

Comment: @RickJames, I will use the temporary table to join with `InnoDB` tables, if `MySQL` picks the `MyISAM` as a storage engine, will it cause table-level lock on both tables? Because, as far as I know, in `JOIN` if one of the tables is `MyISAM`, all `InnoDB` tables act as `MyISAM`. In that case, should I explicitly tell `MySQL` to pick `Memory` or `InnoDB` as a storage engine?

Comment: @Shahin - Temp tables created as part of executing a `SELECT` do not care about transactional semantics -- only the 'real' tables care.  That's why `MEMORY` is even an option.

Comment: @RickJames, please, correct me if I'm wrong. When I `JOIN` temporary and 'real' tables, `MySQL` will put a read lock on the 'real' table, right?

Comment: @Shahin - Are you referring to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`?  Or `Using temporary` (as found in `EXPLAIN`)?  InnoDB has no table-level read or write locks.

Comment: @RickJames, sorry for a newbie question, I just want to find out: after creating a temporary table, I will use it in `JOIN` queries like - `SELECT * FROM tempTable t1 INNER JOIN productCategories t2 ON t1.id = t2.productId `;      `productCategories ` is a real table with `InnoDB` storage engine and `tempTable` will use `MyISAM` or `MEMORY` (MySQL will decide which one to use). Now I am wondering if joining different storage engines will cause any performance problems, bottlenecks or anything?

Comment: @Shahin -In _that_ case (where you had to do `CREATE TEMPOARRY TABLE tempTable...`), you have to specify which storage engine; MySQL will only 'default' to a constant from my.cnf....

Comment: @Shahin - Since no one else is touching tempTable, the locks _on it_ are not relevant.  The Engine of `tempTable` will not change the locking on table(s) `JOINed` to it.

Comment: @Shahin - Subquery caching exists in MariaDB but not MySQL.  InnoDB caches _blocks_, not queries, not tables, not indexes, in its buffer_pool.  MEMORY lives in RAM.  MyISAM caches index blocks in the key_buffer.  The "Query cache" caches `SELECT` statements (not subqueries) and their results.  But writes to the relevant tables quickly purge the QC.

Comment: @Shahin - the overhead of `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` is _usually_ too high to make that approach cost-effective.  (YMMV - Your Mileage May Vary).

Comment: @Shahin - In 8.0, you could use `WITH` as an alternative to a `TEMPORARY` table.

Comment: @RickJames, thank you for the reply, sir. Since I am not a DBA, I did a quick research about table locking. I am concerned about joining `InnoDB` and non-InnoDB (`MEMORY` in that case) tables because two different storage engines can cause table-level blocks. I just need to make sure that joining `InnoDB` table with `MEMORY` table will not cause any table-level blocking on join tables.

Comment: @RickJames, 
Please have a look this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475283/joining-innodb-tables-with-myisam-tables) Whenever there are joins involving MyISAM and InnoDB, InnoDB tables will end up having table-level lock behavior instead of row-level locking because of MyISAM's involvement in the query and MVCC cannot be applied to the MyISAM data.

Comment: @RickJames I created another question for that [topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245297/how-to-avoid-running-multiple-selects-with-the-same-subquery-join), I am not sure if it is safe to use temporary tables. A user warned me about connection can be lost or unavailable problem, he suggests using static tables with MEMORY storage engine instead. I would be glad to hear your opinions about it :)

Comment: @RickJames, I also added `CTE` statement -- please see the update 1 section: [topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245297/how-to-avoid-running-multiple-selects-with-the-same-subquery-join). However, I am not sure if it fits my case. If `CTE` is only valid for one statement, I need to run the same query over and over again, which is not cost-effective.